# Calculating the position of a div depending on the height of another div

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have two div boxes.

CSS:

```
.heros {

    background-color: 817B6F;
    position: absolute;
    width: 10%;
    top: 10%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0.7%;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: red;
    border-style: solid;
}
#h1 {left: 32.9%; top: 10%;}

#h2 {left: 32.9%; top: 13%;}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="heros" id="h1"> </div>
<div class="heros" id="h2"> </div>
```

In fullscreen, `#h1` will stay perfectly on top of `#h2`. But if I change the display ration, they will start to overlap or spread out.

I want them to stop doing that. My Idea would be:

Pseudocode:

```
#h1 {left:32,9%; top: 10%;}
#h2 {left:32,9%; top: calc (10% + height of h1);}
```

Is something like that possible? Maybe by using Javascript?

Edit:

I tried @Alvaro und @zgood 's solution with success. When I wanted to scale it up and implent it to my project, I realized it would be better to use the `getElementByClass()` function

Edit 2:

Corrected some typos.

Edit 3: I got the code to work now. The only problem is, it only works after i resized the browser window.

CSS:

```
<style>
* {
    background-color: #151515;
}


.h {
    align-self: center;
    width: 96%;
    height 100%;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0px;
    border-color: 817B6F;

}


.heroes1 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: 817B6F;
    position: absolute;
    width: 10%;
    top: 10%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0.7%;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: black;
    border-style: solid;
}

.heroes2 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: 817B6F;
    position: absolute;
    width: 10%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0.7%;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: black;
    border-style: solid;
}


#h1 {left: 21.5%;  border-top-left-radius: 5px;}
#h2 {left: 32.9%;}
#h3 {left: 44.3%;}
#h4 {left: 55.7%;}    
#h5 {left: 67.1%; border-top-right-radius: 5px;}
#h6 {left: 21.5%; border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;}
#h7 {left: 32.9%;}
#h8 {left: 44.3%;}
#h9 {left: 55.7%;}    
#h10{left: 67.1%; border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;}





</style>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="heroes1" id="h1">

<img class= "h" name= "Warrior" src="https://placehold.it/256" />
</div>

<div class="heroes1" id="h2">

<img class= "h" name= "Warrior" src="https://placehold.it/256" />
</div>

<div class="heroes1" id="h3">

<img class= "h" name= "Warrior" src="https://placehold.it/256" />
</div>

<div class="heroes1" id="h4">

<img class= "h" name= "Warrior" src="https://placehold.it/256" />
</div>

<div class="heroes1" id="h5">

<img class= "h" name= "Warrior" src="https://placehold.it/256" />
</div>

<div class="heroes2" id="h6">

<img class= "h" name= "Warrior" src="https://placehold.it/256" />
</div>

<div class="heroes2" id="h7">

<img class= "h" name= "Warrior" src="https://placehold.it/256" />
</div>

<div class="heroes2" id="h8">

<img class= "h" name= "Warrior" src="https://placehold.it/256" />
</div>

<div class="heroes2" id="h9">

<img class= "h" name= "Warrior" src="https://placehold.it/256" />
</div>

<div class="heroes2" id="h10">

<img class= "h" name= "Warrior" src="https://placehold.it/256" />
</div>
```

JS:

```
<script>
    var heroes1 = document.getElementsByClassName('heroes1'),
    heroes2 = document.getElementsByClassName('heroes2'),
    onResize = function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < heroes1.length; i++) {
            heroes2[i].style.top = (heroes1[i].offsetHeight + heroes1[i].getBoundingClientRect().top)
        }
    }, 
    init = (function() {
    onResize();
    window.addEventListener("resize", onResize, false);
    })();

</script>
```

Comment: Absolute positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Comment: Flexbox might be a better choice

Comment: @Alter you have some typos and mistakes in the code from your edit. `<img class= "h" name= Warrior src="https://placehold.it/256/"` is not closed and `getElementByClass` should be `getElementsByClassName`.

Comment: @ChrisHappy yes, I didnt notice the typo in the *s* too :)

Comment: As your comment provides enough info, I'm deleting mine. :)

Comment: @ChrisHappy I updated my code with yours, it works now but only once I resized the window. I posted my new code in the orignal Question.

Answer (score 1):

Using just JavaScript:

```js
var $h1 = document.getElementById('h1'),
  $h2 = document.getElementById('h2');

$h2.style.top = ($h1.offsetHeight + $h1.getBoundingClientRect().top) + 'px';
```

```css
.heros {
  background-color: #817B6F;
  position: absolute;
  width: 10%;
  top: 10%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 0.7%;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: red;
  border-style: solid;
}
#h1 {
  left: 32.9%;
  top: 10%;
}
#h2 {
  left: 32.9%;
}
```

```html
<div class="heros" id="h1"></div>
<div class="heros" id="h2"></div>
```

If using jQuery is an option:

```js
$(function() {

  var $h1 = $('#h1'),
    $h2 = $('#h2');

  $h2.css('top', ($h1.outerHeight() + $h1.offset().top));

});
```

```css
.heros {
  background-color: #817B6F;
  position: absolute;
  width: 10%;
  top: 10%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 0.7%;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: red;
  border-style: solid;
}
#h1 {
  left: 32.9%;
  top: 10%;
}
#h2 {
  left: 32.9%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="heros" id="h1"></div>
<div class="heros" id="h2"></div>
```

If JavaScript is not an option I would suggest using a container. You can position this container absolute and with some of the properties you were assigning to the `.heros`. Then position the `.heros` relative.

```css
.heros {
  background-color: #817B6F;
  position: relative;
  top: 10%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 14%;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: red;
  border-style: solid;
}
#container {
  position: absolute;
  left: 32.9%;
  top: 10%;
  width: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="heros" id="h1"></div>
  <div class="heros" id="h2"></div>
</div>
```

---

Side note: There is a typo in your `background-color`, it should be `#817B6F`

Comment: Hey. Javascript is definitly an option.

Comment: Why would you choose to do it any other way even if JS was an option?

Comment: The div elements are later to be animated and change their position entirely on click. I am not sure how to to this, if they are inside of a container.

Comment: @Alter , I added a JavaScript (jQuery) option too.

Comment: @Alvaro Thank you. I copied your code into my editor, tagged the JS part with `<script></script`> and tagged the CSS part with `<style></style>`, but i can not make it work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Alter the code I posted is using jQuery. If you are not using it then a pure JavaScript option would be better than importing jQuery just for this.

Comment: @Alvaro I am pretty sure I will use it later in my project. I imported JQuery with `<script src="ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/…;` to no success. What would be a pure JS option to do this?

Comment: @Alter there you have it, just JavaScript.

Comment: @Alter Make sure you execute the javascript when the page as fully loaded. For the jQuery option the OP should wrap the code in `$(function() { ... }`

Comment: Presumably you'll want to recalculate the top position on resize events too, for when the user resizes their browser? ```var h1 = document.getElementById('h1'),
  h2 = document.getElementById('h2'),
  onResize = function() {
    h2.style.top = (h1.offsetHeight + h1.getBoundingClientRect().top) + 'px';
  },
  init = (function() {
    onResize();
    window.addEventListener("resize", onResize, false);
  })();```

Comment: @Alvaro Thank you guys. The JS code is simple enough´for me to understand the syntax. Is it also possible to use getElementByClass() function on subclasses? That would help me a lot.

Comment: I edited my Post with my new code, in which I tried to implent this method in my project.

Answer (score 1):

Use a flex

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 10%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 32.9%;
  top: 10%;
}
.heros {
  background-color: #817B6F;
  min-height: 1em;
  margin-bottom: .2em;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: red;
  border-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="heros" id="h1">
    <p>
      bla
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="heros" id="h2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The `flex` parts of this are redundant. The elements will naturally flow like that if you remove `display: flex;` and `flex-direction: column;`. The important part of this solution is adding the wrapper.

Comment: if only `heros` is a not inline elements. so that this redundancy is more helpful than not

Comment: We can see that `.heros` are _not_ inline elements by the sample code.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a few problems:

- `name=W arrior` should be `name="Warrior"`
- get `.getElementByClass` should be [`.getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName). As you are returning an array, for loop is the simplest way to apply code to every element in the array.

```js
//Select .heroes and .heroes2 and give them a class
var heroes1 = document.getElementsByClassName('heroes')
var heroes2 = document.getElementsByClassName('heroes2')

//Make a function that is called when onResize is called
var onResize = function() {
  
    //Make variable i; Continue loop as long as i is less 
    //than the number of .hero elements there are; After one 
    //occurance of loop, plus 1 to i.
    for (var i = 0; i < heroes1.length; i++) {
      heroes2[i].style.top = (heroes1[i].offsetHeight + heroes1[i].getBoundingClientRect().top)

      //This sets the height of the "i" of heroes2 to the height + border + padding of the "i" heroes1 AND the how far .hero1 is from the top of the window.
      
      // E.g if i = 0 and the first heroes1 element had:
      //   a height of 10px
      //   a padding of 0
      //   a border or 1px 
      //   and 25px from the top of the window
      // Then the first heroes2 element would receive this
      // CSS style {  top: 37px  } (10px + 1px[top border] 
      // + 1px[bottom border] + 25px)
    }
  }

// I'm updating the code below because I do it a different 
//way

  window.onresize = onResize() //This runs when the window is resized
  onResize(); //This runs when the code gets called
```

```css
.h {
  align-self: center;
  width: 96%;
  height 100%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0px;
  border-color: 817B6F;
}
.heroes {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: 817B6F;
  position: absolute;
  width: 10%;
  top: 10%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 0.7%;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
}
.heroes2 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: 817B6F;
  position: absolute;
  width: 10%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 0.7%;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
}
#h1 {
  left: 21.5%;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
}
#h2 {
  left: 32.9%;
}
#h3 {
  left: 44.3%;
}
#h4 {
  left: 55.7%;
}
#h5 {
  left: 67.1%;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}
#h6 {
  left: 21.5%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}
#h7 {
  left: 32.9%;
}
#h8 {
  left: 44.3%;
}
#h9 {
  left: 55.7%;
}
#h10 {
  left: 67.1%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="heroes" id="h1">

  <img class="h" name="Warrior" src="https://placehold.it/256/" <div class="heroes" id="h2">

  <img class="h" name="Warrior" src="https://placehold.it/256/" />
</div>

<div class="heroes" id="h3">

  <img class="h" name="Warrior" src="https://placehold.it/256/" />
</div>

<div class="heroes" id="h4">

  <img class="h" name="Warrior" src="https://placehold.it/256/" />
</div>

<div class="heroes" id="h5">

  <img class="h" name="Warrior" src="https://placehold.it/256/" />
</div>

<div class="heroes2" id="h6">

  <img class="h" name="Warrior" src="https://placehold.it/256/" />
</div>

<div class="heroes2" id="h7">

  <img class="heroes2" name="Warrior" src="https://placehold.it/256/" />
</div>

<div class="heroes2" id="h8">

  <img class="heroes2" name="Warrior" src="https://placehold.it/256/" />
</div>

<div class="heroes2" id="h9">

  <img class="h" name="Warrior" src="https://placehold.it/256/" />
</div>

<div class="heroes2" id="h10">

  <img class="h" name="Warrior" src="https://placehold.it/256/" />
```

Comment: Thank you. Still does not work though. Does it run for you?

Comment: @Alter To also run when the code is loaded, just write `onResize();` anywhere after you write it. See updated code.

Comment: I included `onResize();` at the bottom of my JS. Still no success, the same problem remains.

Comment: Could you show me how to do make a simple function like `function resize (){......}` out of the function? I don't really understand what is going on in the JS code. Could you explain it a bit?